# OCaml : add element to a list inside an Array

Tags: ocaml, complexity-theory, mutability

I'm making a basic program in OCaml, in which I use graphs.
I defined a graph as :

```
type 'a graph = ('a * int list) array;;
```

where elements in the array are the vertexes, and the elements in the lists are the edges from the vertex. I need to be able to build a graph in O(|V|+|E|) which seems legit.
So i first built the vertex array, with empty lists. Now, I want to add the edges.

The only way that I came out with is this :

```
let addEdge a b g = g.(a)<-(fst g.(a), b::snd g.(a));;
```

I'm not really sure about this, but it seems to me this is linear in the degree of a at the time I do this. This would mean if one of my vertices is connected to every other vertices, it will take me O(n^2)

Am I right ?
If I am, do I have anyway to keep this linear ?

Comment: I don't understand what are the `'a` for. Just contents ? Or is it to add some informations in the graph ?

Comment: Yes, I'm actually solving 2-CNF-QBF in linear time, my vertexes are litterals,  and there's an edge from not a to b, and from not b to a, if I have a clause (a or b) — where a and b are litterals too —

Comment: Ok. Anyway, I kept it ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let's see what you do (I prefer to rewrite it in a more readable way ;-)):

```
let addEdge a b g = 
  let (c, al) = g.(a) in
  g.(a) <- (c, b :: al);;
```

For each edge `a -> b` you add this edge to your array by adding `b` to the list corresponding to `a`. Getting the content of an array is O(1) and adding an element to the list is O(1) too so, if we resume what you did

- O(|V|) to create the array
- O(|E|) to add the edges
- O(|V| + |E|) to create and fill the array

It looks like a linear way of doing. The problem will emerge when you'll have to find if two vertices are connected. ;-)

Comment: Setting the content of an array to "x" is constant ? It doesn't take O(x) ?

Comment: @Anatole Dahan: Standard data structures (i.e. lists, arrays, and so on) are optimised so access to an element is O(1), and so is setting this element.

Comment: @RichouHunter Creating and accessing an arbitrary element is O(1) in arrays but in lists, accessing the i-th element will be done in O(i). ;-)

Comment: @AnatoleDahan If the answer is ok for you, remember to accept it ;-)